# Get user info from two tables using relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have model user and user_data. I want to take some data from user and user data. My code looks like:

User model:

```
public function user_data()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserData', 'user_id');
}

public function getUserById($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    return $user;
}
```

UserData model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

User controller

```
public function getUser($id) 
{
    //$user = $this->model->getUserById($id);

    $user = User::with('user_data')->find(3);

    dd($user->sex);
    return view('user', compact('user'));
}
```

How I can get data from two tables? When i dump sex i get null, but I have it in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add also the local key in the relationship like this

```
public function user_data()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserData', 'user_id','your local key');
}

$user = User::with('user_data')->where('id',$id)->first(); // Get the data like this
```

After that you can check what is it in like this

```
$user->user_data[0]->sex // Not $user->sex
```

If it's not working try to swap the foreign key and local key places.

Also you have to take the data like this

Comment: What it is that local key? Where to find this?

Comment: Try to fetch the data as i said first $user->user_data->sex

Comment: I got this Property [sex] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Try this

`User::with('user_data')->where('id',$id)->first()`
After that dump the `dd($user->user_data); ` and post the output

Comment: What do you mean ? try `dd($user->user_data->toArray())` and post the output so i can solve your problem

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => array:20 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "sex" => "male"

Comment: Okay so it's working now right ? You can access the data with offset like 
`$user->user_data[0]->sex` Access it like this because your relationship is hasMany if u want single try hasOne

Comment: Why hasone? I think hasmany because one user has many data, right?

Comment: this also work $user_data = UserData::where ('user_id', $id)->first();

Comment: If everything is alright please accept the answer so we can help other ppl too